# How to make app show in pick image from menu

Tags: android, image-gallery

I am kind of stuck here, I have created a gallery app but for some reasons I do not know how to make it be recognized by the system as a gallery app so that I can pick images from it from other apps e.g Whatsapp, I see other 3rd party appearing on the menu except mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this in your Manifest

```
   <activity android:name="YourActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

And then handle the intent when your activity gets opened and get the URI of the image from the EXTRAS.

Comment: Just edited my answer. GET_CONTENT is to let apps pick content using your app and ACTION_VIEW is to let other apps open and view content in your app.

Comment: could you also help with code that can send back the image to the calling app?

Comment: `Uri resultUri = // URI of the image
Intent result = new Intent();
result.setData(resultUri);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result);
finish();`